# Visual FoxPro 9 compatibility with Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, visual-foxpro, foxpro

What compatibility issues have you found when developing with Visual FoxPro 9 on Windows Vista?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My company has no current plans to move to vista, so we haven't tested compatability issues yet.   Doug Hennig has an excellent article on the subject however:

http://my.advisor.com/articles.nsf/aid/18897

These links describe some issues as well:

http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~VistaAeroIssues~VFP

http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~SP2problemwithVistaandBorderstyle~VFP

Answer (score 0):

Our company found some issues with the Vista Windows color and appearance settings. Evidently FoxPro does not handle the new Vista graphics very well. I believe we fixed these issues by having the users switch back to the Windows "Classic" appearance settings.